# Unable to parse self closing xml tag

Tags: objective-c, xml

I have a very unusual problem.
I am using NSXMLParser to parse XML but it is not being able to parse self closing tags!
If the XML is something like "< media:something .......  / >", when I parse it and output the elementName in didStartElement: method, there's no output for the particular tag.
All other tags which are not self closing are however being displayed.
Any idea what is going on and what can be done to fix it?

Thanks in advance! :))

Comment: If devio's answer is wrong, you are going to have to post some code to show what you are doing.  We are not telepathic.

Comment: M sorry well, here's the XML: 

<media:thumbnail width="107" height="82" url="http://www.website.tv/thumb/height-82,width-107,msid-4350691.cms" />


Here all I want to do is grab the URL so that I can display the image.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a space between / and > ? Remove it to read as />

Comment: Hey, thanks...but nope, there's no space... :(( Anything else that I could do..please do suggest...